# Remove squashed file from history

Tags: git

We had a PR in our company from one of my colleagues who accidentally pushed some big file. In next commit he removed it from repository. File was removed from branch HEAD but of course it was in history. I didn't want to filter-branch and rewrite history.

I thought that the easiest way will be to merge this PR with squash option. Same PR consisted of commit which added file and commit which removed file so after squash there shouldn't be any reference to file (after branch close) and it will disappear. Unfortunately there is some reference to file.

I'm searching for this file with:

```
git rev-list --objects --all | grep filename
```

and it appears in rev-list. I can access it with

```
git show filehash
```

File doesn't appear in git log after typing command:

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A | grep filename
```

It's also missing in git fsck.

I tried

```
git gc --prune=now
```

No effect.

How can I remove this file from repository?

Answer (score 1):

Run `git reflog expire --expire=now --all` before your `git gc --prune=now`.

Git is very reluctant to delete internal objects:

- *Any* name that can find the object will keep it alive.  This specifically includes reflogs, which will find otherwise un-find-able commits, which will then find internal file objects.
- Any object not at least 14 days old by default will not be deleted.  This gives Git commands some time to complete, since it's possible that a new commit or other operation is running while `git gc` runs.

You're carefully defeating the second safety switch using `--prune=now`, but the first safety switch will retain the *commits* for at least 30 days by default.

Note that forcibly expiring reflogs can lose stuff you might want after all (e.g., the stash stack), so be pretty sure you really want to do this, before you do it.

Comment: After `git reflog expire --expire=now --all` and `git gc --prune=now` file is still in `git rev-list --objects --all`

Comment: I assume you've deleted the branch name that you used when you created the commit in question. If not, do that too.

Comment: Yes I did. I closed PR with close branch option and then did everything on fresh repo clone. Branch is not listed in `git branch -a`

Comment: OK: it sounds like you did all the relevant items in the "shrink a repository after filter-branch" (see [the `git filter-branch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)). The fact that `git rev-list --all` finds the object in question means it's in some referenced tag or commit, but without access to the repository, I can't say which one.

Comment: How can I find out which tag or commit reference to this object? As I mentioned `git log` can't find it. Will deleting this object from `.git/objects` solve the problem?

Comment: There are some scripts in some StackOverflow posts for finding commits that refer to blob objects. Use those to find the commits, then do a reachability test on that commit for each refname (with `git for-each-ref --contains`). If that doesn't turn anything up, it must be some non-ref-name reference, such as a reflog entry. It could be a stash, for instance, if for some reason `git reflog expire` *doesn't* expire stash reflogs.

Comment: But, don't just delete the object itself: that might not be possible (it might be packed) and if it is possible, that just results in a broken commit or tree object, leading to other problems.